# Issue in PyQt within Python - WebBrowser Project

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-webbrowser, pygui

The code below is a WebBrowser code.
The problem is when I want to switch tabs which happens in the function 'SwitchTab'. I've checked that in function 'SwitchTab', my 'Tab_Content' variable is empty-as it prints 'None'- and here is the problem. I couldn't figure out why would that be empty.(I've Bolded the partS of the code which stands for the Issue)
Thanks In Advance...

P.S: I'm using Python3.8 and PyCharm4.5.4 and Also PyQt5

```
import sys
import os
import json

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout,
                             QHBoxLayout, QPushButton, QLabel,
                             QLineEdit, QTabBar, QFrame, QStackedLayout, QTabWidget)

from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QWindow, QImage
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *




class AddressBar(QLineEdit):
     def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

     def mousePressEvent(self, e):
         self.selectAll()


class App(QFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.CreateApp()
        self.setWindowTitle("Web Browser")
        self.setBaseSize(500 , 500)

    def CreateApp(self):

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)

        *#Creating Tabs*
        self.TabBar = QTabBar(movable=True, tabsClosable=True)
        self.TabBar.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.TabClose)
        **self.TabBar.tabBarClicked.connect(self.SwitchTab)**

        self.TabBar.setCurrentIndex(0)

        *#Tabs List*
        self.TabCount = 0
        self.Tabs = []

        *#Creating the AddressBar*
        self.ToolBar = QWidget()
        self.ToolBarLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.AddressBar = AddressBar()

        self.ToolBar.setLayout(self.ToolBarLayout)
        self.ToolBarLayout.addWidget(self.AddressBar)

        *#NewTab Button*
        self.AddTabButton = QPushButton("+")
        self.AddTabButton.clicked.connect(self.AddTab)

        self.ToolBarLayout.addWidget(self.AddTabButton)

        *#Main View*
        self.Container = QWidget()
        self.Container.layout = QStackedLayout()
        self.Container.setLayout(self.Container.layout)


        self.layout.addWidget(self.TabBar)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.ToolBar)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.Container)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        
        self.AddTab()
        self.show()

    def TabClose(self, i):
        self.TabBar.removeTab(i)
        print(self.TabCount)
        print(self.Tabs)

    def AddTab(self):
        i = self.TabCount

        self.Tabs.append(QWidget())
        self.Tabs[i].layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.Tabs[i].setObjectName("Tab " + str(i))

        *#Generate WebView*
        self.Tabs[i].content = QWebEngineView()
        self.Tabs[i].content.load(QUrl.fromUserInput("http://google.com"))

        *#Add WebView to Tabs layout*
        self.Tabs[i].layout.addWidget(self.Tabs[i].content)

        *#Set top level tab [] to layout*
        self.Tabs[i].setLayout(self.Tabs[i].layout)

        *#Add tab to top level StackedWidget*
        self.Container.layout.addWidget(self.Tabs[i])
        self.Container.layout.setCurrentWidget(self.Tabs[i])

        *#Set the tab at top of screen*
        self.TabBar.addTab("New Tab - " + str(i))
        self.TabBar.setTabData(i, "tab" + str(i))
        self.TabBar.setCurrentIndex(i)
        self.TabCount += 1

    **def SwitchTab(self, i):
        Tab_Data = self.TabBar.tabData(i)
        print("tab: ", Tab_Data)
        Tab_Content = self.findChild(QWidget, Tab_Data)
        print(Tab_Content)
        self.Container.layout.setCurrentWidget(Tab_Content)**


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = App()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Please do not add asterisks to try to "format" the code, use comments instead (or include the code between <pre><code></code></pre> tags and use actual <b></b> tags). Your code must be readable as *pure* code, and possibly it can be copied/pasted/run as it is. Please edit your question to remove unnecessary characters, and ensure its syntax is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the [findChild](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChild) method takes the [objectName](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#objectName-prop) into it, not the tabData you set. in this case, the solution is simple. Just set the objectName and the tabData with the same parameter.

```py
self.TabBar.setTabData(i, "Tab " + str(i))
self.Tabs[i].setObjectName("Tab " + str(i))
```

Comment: Yeah, You are right... What a bad mistake...   Thank You...